# Отрисовка анимации

Tags: java, android, view

Необходимо отрисавать анимацию заполнение бутылки водой. Есть 2 картинки: сама бутылка и синий прямоугольник. Я хочу задавать размер этого прямоугольника, тем самым создавая эффект заполнения бутылки. Но проблема в размерах, на разных экранах размер разный. Вопрос: как узнать размер `ImageViev` в `px`, ну или `dp`?Метод `imgBottle.getHeight();` возвращает 0. Похожие темы находил, но механизма не понял. Дайте толковую ссылку, а еще лучше объясните)
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы задали ряд вопросов в одном, сделать анимацию, задать размеры, узнать размеры px или dp. Это все не так сложно, но на каждый из них абсолютно разный ответ. Помимо этого? создать такую анимацию можно разными способами и какой подходит Вам?

Comment: Исправил. Вопрос один - как узнать размер отрисованой картинки.

Comment: На самом деле у Вас подход к решению задачи изначально неправильный. Вам не надо программно узнавать сколько ширина и высота вашей бутылки. Объект можно описать в xml полностью.

Comment: Саму бутылку описать в `xml`?

Comment: да, и бутылку и воду в ней, одним объектом

Comment: А анимация заполнения будет обычная scaleAnimation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void getViewProperty(View view)
{
    int height = view.getHeight();
    int width = view.getWidth();
    Log.d("...", "height = " + height);
    Log.d("...", "width = " + width);
}
```

Проблема у Вас в том, что вы пытались получить параметры ещё не нарисованного элемента, вставьте этот метод в слушатель, например нажатие на кнопку и получите результат.

```
getViewProperty(myView);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!